# API response for Menu multiple category array combine laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I am trying to create an API for my react js and laravel as backend. So for menu I have Category, Subcategory, and Further Subcategory. I need to combine all the results as below,

```
{
  "response": 200,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 15,
      "name": "dfdfhdf rtuydf",
      "slug": "dfdfhdf-rtuydf",
      "subcategory": [
        {
            "sub_id": 15,
            "sub_name": "dfdfhdf rtuydf",
            "sub_slug": "dfdfhdf-rtuydf"
            "fsubcategory": [
              {
                "fsub_id": 15,
                "fsub_name": "dfdfhdf rtuydf",
                "fsub_slug": "dfdfhdf-rtuydf"
              },
              ...
            ]
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    ....
  ]
}
```

I have tried using the below code, but the result is not showing as expected.

```
$list = Category::select('id', 'name', 'slug')->where(array('in_menu' => 1, 'status' => 1, 'deleted_at' => null))->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

$array = [];

foreach ($list as $category) {
        $sublist = Subcategory::select('id', 'name', 'slug')->where(array('category_id' => $category->id, 'status' => 1, 'deleted_at' => null))->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

        $first = array("id" => $category->id, "name" => $category->name, "slug" => $category->slug);
        array_push($array, array("category" => $first));

        foreach($sublist as $subcategory) {
            array_push($array, array("subcategory" => array("sub_id" => $subcategory->id, "sub_name" => $subcategory->name, "sub_slug" => $subcategory->slug)));
        }
}

return response()->json(['response' => 200, 'data' => $array]);
```

The result for the above code is,

```
{
"response": 200,
"data": [
    {
    "category": {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "dfdfhdf rtuydf",
        "slug": "dfdfhdf-rtuydf"
    }
    },
    {
    "subcategory": {
        "sub_id": 6,
        "sub_name": "Test Subcategory 221",
        "sub_slug": "test-subcategory-221"
    }
    },
]
}
```

How to achieve the required result. I am really stuck here.

Please check the below code for recent output.

```
$list = Category::select('id', 'name', 'slug')->where(array('in_menu' => 1, 'status' => 1, 'deleted_at' => null))->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

    $data = [];

    foreach ($list as $category) {
        $sublist = Subcategory::select('id', 'name', 'slug')->where(array('category_id' => $category->id, 'status' => 1, 'deleted_at' => null))->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

        $item = [
            "id" => $category->id,
            "name" => $category->name,
            "slug" => $category->slug,
            "subcategory" => [],
        ];

        foreach($sublist as $subcategory) {
            $fsublist = Fsubcategory::select('id', 'name', 'slug')->where(array('subcategory_id' => $subcategory->id, 'status' => 1, 'deleted_at' => null))->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

            $item["subcategory"][] = [
                "sub_id" => $subcategory->id,
                "sub_name" => $subcategory->name,
                "sub_slug" => $subcategory->slug,
                "fsubcategory" => [],
            ];

            foreach($fsublist as $fsubcategory) {
                $item["fsubcategory"][] = [
                    "fsub_id" => $fsubcategory->id,
                    "fsub_name" => $fsubcategory->name,
                    "fsub_slug" => $fsubcategory->slug,
                ];
            }
        }

        $data[] = $item;
    }

    return response()->json(['response' => 200, 'data' => $data]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$list = Category::select('id', 'name', 'slug')
                ->where([
                    'in_menu' => 1,
                    'status' => 1,
                    'deleted_at' => null
                ])
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->get();

$data = [];

foreach ($list as $category) {
    $sublist = Subcategory::select('id', 'name', 'slug')
                           ->where([
                               'category_id' => $category->id,
                               'status' => 1,
                               'deleted_at' => null
                           ])
                           ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                           ->get();

    $item = [
        "id" => $category->id,
        "name" => $category->name,
        "slug" => $category->slug,
        "subcategory" => [],
    ];

    foreach($sublist as $subcategory) {
            $fsublist = Fsubcategory::select('id', 'name', 'slug')->where(array('subcategory_id' => $subcategory->id, 'status' => 1, 'deleted_at' => null))->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
            
            $subitems = [];
            foreach($fsublist as $fsubcategory) {
                $subitems[] = [
                    "fsub_id" => $fsubcategory->id,
                    "fsub_name" => $fsubcategory->name,
                    "fsub_slug" => $fsubcategory->slug,
                ];
            }

            $item["subcategory"][] = [
                "sub_id" => $subcategory->id,
                "sub_name" => $subcategory->name,
                "sub_slug" => $subcategory->slug,
                "fsubcategory" => $subitems,
            ];
        }

    $data[] = $item;
}

return response()->json(['response' => 200, 'data' => $data]);
```

Comment: `$subcategory` not defined

Comment: I did not modify your queries

Comment: Ahh, i see it. My bad. 1 sec

Comment: If another listing is there, then how to include inside `subcategory`. I have updated the required output in the Question.

Comment: Updated. Please open a new question next time.